# Möbius inversion

Tags: number-theory

The Möbius inversion formula says given two arithmetic functions $\hat{g}(k)$ and $g(k)$ related by $$\sum_{d\mid k}\hat{g}(d)=g(k)$$
Then $$\sum_{d\mid k}\mu(d)g\left(\frac{k}{d}\right)=\hat{g}(k)$$
Can someone give me a very elementary proof of this?

I don't know anything about analytic number theory, though I know the definition of the Möbius function, and have used it before with out ever reading to deeply into it for example: I know that,
$\frac{x}{1-x}=x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$
And that if I subtract the even powers I get,
$\frac{x}{1-x}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}=x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9+\cdots$
And then If I subtract the the powers that are multiples of 3 I get,
$\frac{x}{1-x}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-(\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}-\frac{x^6}{1-x^6})=x+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+\cdots$
Continuing in this matter one sees we are essentially yielding combinations of the original sum where the argument is a combination of distinct primes, and the coefficients are determined by weather or not the number of primes is even or odd. So by the definition of the Möbius function I can easily see, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)x^k}{1-x^k}=x$, although the first theorem I mentioned doesn't seem so obvious to me, and so I would appreciate a simple proof.

Comment: Proof at: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_Inversion_Formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a proof in the spirit of generating functions, we may use (formal) Dirichlet series.

We have the Euler product factorization

$$\zeta(s)=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$

and hence

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}.$$

Set $g(n):=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\hat{g}(d)$ and use the substitution $n=dm$ to obtain

$$G(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{d\mid n}\hat{g}(d)n^{-s}=\left(\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\hat{g}(d)}{d^s}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^s}\right)=\hat{G}(s)\zeta(s).$$

Multiply both sides by $\zeta(s)^{-1}$ to obtain

$$\hat{G}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\hat{g}(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}G(s)=\left(\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(d)}{d^s}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{g(m)}{m^s}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{dm=n}\mu(d)g(m).$$

Comparing coefficients gives the result.

*Remark 1*. Convergence is not an issue since we are working with *formal* Dirichlet series. We say a sequence $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m}n^{-s})_{m=1}^\infty$ of series converges to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nn^{-s}$ as $m\to\infty$ if each sequence $(a_{n,m})_{m=1}^\infty$ converges to $c_n$ and (a much stronger condition) is *eventually constant*. This allows us to interpret many of the operations used above rigorously.

*Remark 2*. This is more or less the same proof as the usual, functional one (involving [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)), only that sequences are encoded as analytic (really, algebraic-number-theoretic) gadgets. Indeed, if $A(s)$ and $B(s)$ are Dirichlet series with coefficients $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ resp. then $A(s)B(s)$ has coefficients $(a\star b)_n$, the convolution of the two sequences. The utility here is that it is especially easy to see $(\mu\star1)=\delta$ and the associativity of $\star$ follows from associativity of the usual multiplication in the ring of formal Dirichlet series.

Answer (score 4):

If $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ are two sequences, then define the convolution as $$(a \star b)(n) = \sum_{d \vert n} a(d) b(n/d)$$
First note that
$$\sum_{d \vert n} \mu(d) = \sum_{d \vert n} \mu(n/d) = (1 \star \mu)(n) = \delta(n) = \begin{cases}1 & n=0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{(Why?)}$$
We have that
$$\left(\hat{g} \star 1 \right)(n) = g(n)$$
Hence, we have 
$$\hat{g}(n) = (\hat{g} \star \delta)(n) = (\hat{g} \star(1 \star \mu))(n) = ((\hat{g} \star 1) \star \mu)(n) = (g \star \mu)(n)$$

**EDIT**

Let $n=p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where $a_l \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The only terms that contribute to $\sum_{d \vert n} \mu(d)$ is $d$'s of the form $d = p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_k^{b_k}$ where $b_l \in \{0,1\}$. Half of these $d$'s will have $\mu(d)$ as $+1$ while the other half will have $\mu(d) = -1$.

Proving the associativity of $\star$ is a nice little exercise, which I will let you work out.

Comment: (One also needs to check associativity of Dirichlet convolution.)

Comment: Im not understanding

Comment: @Ethan Which step is unclear? There are two places where you might find difficulty. The first one is
$$\sum_{d \vert n} \mu(d) = \sum_{d \vert n} \mu(n/d) = (1 \star \mu)(n) = \delta(n) = \begin{cases}1 & n=0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
while the second place where you might find difficulty is to prove that $\star$ is associative (another fact you need to check as anon has rightly pointed out).

Comment: the first one and second

Comment: @Ethan Have updated the solution. Is it clear now?

Comment: Here's a proof of the associativity of ⋆, if you get stuck: http://i.imgur.com/zrSa7.png